# Troubleshooting Database Backup Errors in Odoo

Tags: odoo, database-backups, odoo-16

Database backup error: `Command '['/usr/bin/pg_dump', '--no-owner', '--file=/tmp/tmpnre4kpbf/dump.sql', 'test']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

I am getting this error message when taking backup and for only this database and not for other databases. Can someone help me??Iam using digitalocean server and manager postgres database

[image]

I have tried with rollback the database to few days and it's not working

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i try this,
add one "test" table while was causing this issue then drop that table as seems any object creation you might need to register or update scripts. Hope this will help. thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).